# Resize table unload output field in jcl

Tags: db2, jcl, ibm-connections

I have performed a bmcunld in jcl to direct the output to a dataset.
The problem is that that field had maximum size and I cant read the dataset afterwards being created because it issues teh following error message:

```
 "Invalid Record Length"
```

This is a sample of my unload:

```
//A00BMC   EXEC PROC=BMCUNLD,UTILID=%%JOBNAME,PARAM='NEW',COND=(0,NE),  
//         SUBSYS=subsys                                                  
//SYSREC   DD DSN=datasetname,                               
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG),                                         
//            SPACE=(CYL,(10,10),RLSE),                          
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=1000,BLKSIZE=0)               
//SYSIN    DD *                                                  
  UNLOAD                                                         
  DIRECT NO                                                  
  SELECT  a.data, a.codent, b.text                        
  FROM owner.table_view A,owner.table2_view B  
  WHERE a.cmarca='S' AND a.cestado='P'  AND A.codrc='OK'         
  AND DATE(A.data) > CURRENT DATE - 2 DAYS                
  AND B.cmarca   = A.cmarca                                  
  AND B.chave   = A.data                                 
  WITH UR;
```

Can this problem only be solved by using this dataset as an input to a SORT with an OUTREC PARSE or can I solve the problem directçy in the query?

Comment: Not familiar with BMC's product, but... What is the LRECL and DSORG of your output dataset?  What are the characteristics of the columns in your SELECT statement?  If you have a VARCHAR column whose contents you know to always be less than some shorter fixed length, you _may_ be able to cast it as a CHAR with that shorter length.  Depending on what you're reading the output dataset with, maybe the error has some other root cause.

Comment: What does ISPF 3.1 or TSO LISTD show for the DCB attributes of the output data set? And what program are you running that shows the error message?

Comment: For an unload I suspect the LRECL must match the length of the row being extracted hence the "invalid record length". Have a closer look at the output messages to see if the expected LRECL is specified

Answer (score 0):

Your BLKSIZE looks odd - you have RECFM=FB,LRECL=1000,BLKSIZE=0

At a minimum I would expect RECFM=FB,LRECL=1000,BLKSIZE=1000

You might get away with not specifying BLKSIZE at all (by not giving one) but generally BLKSIZE needs to be some non-zero multiple of LRECL.  Typically, especially if your shop has System Managed Storage (SMS), the system itself will assign an optimal BLKSIZE suitable for the file you are creating.  Your example however where BLKSIZE=0 doesn't even permit one record to be stored in a block.